# Lotka-Volterra Models in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, pseudocode, numerical-methods, differential-equations, conceptual

I am trying to implement an rk4 function to solve 2 differential equations. I have this code that implements the Runge Kutta 4 method:

```
//RK4 method
    func rk4_func(y_array: [Double], f_array: [(([Double], Double) -> Double)], t_val: Double, h_val: Double) -> [Double] {

        let length = y_array.count

        let t_half_step = t_val + h_val / 2.0
        let t_step = t_val + h_val

        var k1 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)
        var k2 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)
        var k3 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)
        var k4 = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)
        var w = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)
        var result = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)

        for i in 0...length {
            k1[i] = h_val * f_array[i](y_array, t_val)
            w[i] = y_array[i] + k1[i]/2.0
        }

        for i in 0...length {
            k2[i] = h_val * f_array[i](w, t_half_step)
            w[i] = y_array[i] + k2[i]/2.0
        }

        for i in 0...length {
            k3[i] = h_val * f_array[i](w, t_half_step)
            w[i] = y_array[i] + k3[i]
        }

        for i in 0...length {
            k4[i] = h_val * f_array[i](w, t_step)
        }

        for i in 0...length {
            result[i] = y_array[i] + (k1[i] + 2.0*k2[i] + 2.0*k3[i] + k4[i])/6.0
        }

        print(result)
        return result;

    }
```

But now I need to actually ***use*** it, which is the part I'm confused about. If anyone has experience with numerically computing solutions to differential equations, that would help.

1. What arrays do I need to feed this function?
2. What does the `t_val` argument represent? Is it a maximum time?
3. How does the output "solve" the equation?
4. What does the output give me?
5. In the line `k1[i] = h_val * f_array[i](y_array, t_val)`, what does `f_array[i](y_array, t_val)` mean? Is it saying that for the `i-th` value of f_array, find the corresponding `i-th` value for y_array? Then what does the `t_val` mean there?

For reference, here are the 2 differential equations needed to be solved. The context is that I'm trying to numerically solve these Lotka-Volterra Models to plot a time series and a phase space plot in Xcode (Swift 3.x).

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the call `k2[i] = h_val * f_array[i](w, t_half_step)`, is the result computed as a vector in the first run through the loop? If not then the changed value of `w[i]` would play havoc with the method.

Comment: I think you mean `array`, not vector. Swift uses `arrays`. And yes, all of the `k` variables are `arrays`.

Comment: The question is, at what point is `f_array[1]` evaluated? For everything to go right it should be simultaneously with `f_array[0]`. And it would make the code simpler if it could be done with double vectors (implying vector operations) instead of bare double arrays.

Comment: @LutzL The `for-loop` evaluates `f_array[0]` followed by `f_array[1]`. I don't understand why these 2 particular values should be evaluated at the same time.

Comment: Because you change the argument `w`. The mathematical method demands that the derivative vector is evaluated at the same point for all components.

Comment: Could you give a link to the source of this implementation of the RK4 algorithm or this programming style? On-the-fly I could not find any documentation on this kind of treatment of array return values.

Comment: @LutzL the code is based on this: https://github.com/pdemarest/swift-rk4

Comment: That looks suspicious, the only test case is one-dimensional where this problem is not evident. Try a 2D test case, as simple as `y'=y` with initial values `y0=[ 1.0, 2.0 ]`. The correct behavior is that the second component is always twice the first. -- Or move the evaluation of `f_array` outside the loops, `let k2 = f_array(w, t_half_step)` and inside the loop `k2[i] *= h_val; w[i] = y_array[i] + 0.5*k2[i];`

Comment: @LutzL ok but I still don't get how to even use `f_array` as an argument. Please pretend I am a programmer with ZERO experience - how do I put in the argument for `f_array: [(([Double], Double) -> Double)]`?

Comment: I've added code to my answer that corrects your source both in its interpretation of the RK4 calling conventions and the language version, there are differences from 2014 to 2017. This includes how to pass a function as argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. `y` is the vector of the current state (implemented as double array). `f_array` is a function pointer to a function `doty = f_array(y,t)`.
2. `t_val` is the time for the current state, `h_val` is the time step.
3. One call of `rk4_func` performs the time step from `t_val` to `t_val+h_val` and
4. returns the new state, `y_next = rk4_func(y, f_array, t, h)`.
5. One would have to study the language internals. Hopefully, that is, for the code to work correctly, the first call of `f_array[0](y_array, t_val)` computes the full vector/array-valued result and further calls just extract the components of the cached result.

---

The original code as found at https://github.com/pdemarest/swift-rk4 is severely deficient in its RK4 realization and out-of-date in language standards. A working version as tested at https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/ is

```
import Foundation


func RK4step(y: [Double], f: ([Double], Double) -> [Double], t: Double, h: Double) -> [Double] {

    let length = y.count

    var w = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length )
    var result = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: length)

    let k1 = f(y,t)
    assert(k1.count == y.count, "States and Derivatives must be the same length")
    for i in 0..<length { w[i] = y[i] + 0.5*h*k1[i]  }
    let k2 = f(w, t+0.5*h)
    for i in 0..<length { w[i] = y[i] + 0.5*h*k2[i]  }
    let k3 = f(w,t+0.5*h)
    for i in 0..<length { w[i] = y[i] + h*k3[i]
    }
    let k4 = f(w,t+h)

    for i in 0..<length {
        result[i] = y[i] + (k1[i] + 2.0*k2[i] + 2.0*k3[i] + k4[i])*h/6.0
    }

    return result;
}



func test_exp(){
    // Integrate: y' = y
    // y_0 = 1.0
    // from 0 to 2.0

    var y = [1.0]

    func deriv (y: [Double], t: Double) -> [Double] {
        return [ y[0] ]
    }

    var t = 0.0
    let h = 0.1


    while t < 2.0 {
        y = RK4step(y:y, f:deriv, t:t, h:h)
        t += h
        print("t: \(t), y: \(y[0]) exact: \(exp(t))\n")
    }

    let exact = exp(2.0)
    let error = abs(y[0] - exact)

    assert(error < pow(h, 4.0))
    print("y: \(y[0]) exact: \(exact) error: \(error)\n")

}


print("testing...\n")

test_exp()
```

For the Volterra-Lotka dynamics one would have to change

```
    var y = [150.0, 5.0]

    let a = 5.0
    let b = 1.0
    let eps = 0.1
    let m = 5.0

    func deriv (y: [Double], t: Double) -> [Double] {
        let p = y[0]
        let q = y[1]
        return [ a*p-b*p*q, eps*b*p*q - m*q ]
    }
```

with properly fixed global constants `a,b,eps,m` and a two-dimensional initial value. Add print statements where required.

Comment: In regards to #1, why do I need to pass in `f_array: [(([Double], Double) -> Double)]` instead of just simply `f_array: [Double]`?

Comment: Because that that is the the pointer/reference to the subroutine that implements the function of the ODE `y' = f(y,t)`, not a constant array.

Comment: Ok. So then in `f_array[i](y_array, t_val)` does that mean that we are passing `(y_array, t_val)` as arguments??

Comment: Added a corrected and language-version updated version of the original code.